# How to fix the disappearance of the "\" character when updating a post in the database

Tags: database

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    
                // Search for images and fill the missing dimensions in the current post content
                $post_content = $this->add_image_dimensions( $post->post_content );
    
                // Update the post content in the database only if the new $post_content it is not the same
                // as the current $post->post_content 
                if( $post_content != $post->post_content ) {
    
                    $query = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts SET post_content = '" . $post_content . "' WHERE ID = " . $post->ID;
             
    
                    $wpdb->query( $query );
    
                }
    
                // Add a post meta to the current post to mark it as doone
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_dimensions_filled', 1 );
```

If there is a `\` character in the text of the post, then it disappears. How to fix it?

Would that be correct?

```
...
                if( $post_content != $post->post_content ) {
                 $post_content = wp_slash($post_content);
                    $query = "UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts SET post_content = '" . $post_content . "' WHERE ID = " . $post->ID;
...
```

This variant not work.

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $query ));
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: You should use [`wp_update_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/) to properly update a post (e.g. so that post caches are updated), but if `$post_content` comes from a POST/GET input, then you should unslash the value when you pass it to the function - `wp_update_post( [ 'post_content' => wp_unslash( $post_content ), ... ] )`.

Comment: Also, you should use [`wpdb::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prepare an SQL query for safe execution, or use [`esc_sql()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) to manually escape a variable that you'll use in your SQL queries.

Comment: How will it look in code?

Comment: Why doesn't it work `$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $query ));`

Comment: Actually, the current answer is good - `wp_insert_post()` can also be called in place of `wp_update_post()` so long as you set the `ID` argument to a valid ID. So I'd upvote that answer, if I were you.. and I'm sure he could and would also help you with `wpdb::prepare()`. And sorry for asking, but why do you insist on using a custom query to update the post?

Comment: Because minimum new code

Comment: Well.. Wouldn't it be simpler to call `wp_update_post()` compared to those custom query's code?  And your `prepare()` syntax is incorrect - check the documentation for the correct usage. Basically, though, you need a placeholder like `%s` in the query and the replacement value as the second parameter, e.g. `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = %s", $bar )`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use your friendly neighbourhood WP functions - look - here's one!

[`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

In your case it would be something like:

```php
...
$post_content = $this->add_image_dimensions( $post->post_content );

$update_post = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'ID'           => $post->ID,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
    )
);

// Don't forget error handling
if ( is_wp_error( $update_post ) ) {
    $error_code    = array_key_first( $update_post->errors );
    $error_message = $update_post->errors[ $error_code ][0];
    wp_die( "Post Update Error: Post ID: $post->ID  - $error_message" );
}
...
```

That will correctly add slashes before adding to the DB so they can be stripped correctly on read.

If you do insist on running direct queries, [prepare your damned write statements](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)!

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue receiving post content from database and then `wp_update_post()` eating up slashes and messing up database.

So indeed it works correctly applying this line, before sending post content back to database:

```php
$post_content = wp_slash($post_content);
```

to update post content, as others mentioned, you can simply use:

```php
$my_post = array(
    'ID' => $post->ID,
    'post_content' => $post_content
);

wp_update_post( $my_post );
```